# Django development server dramatically slowed down (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: django

I have a project that was running normally until now when the code base has developed, now running very slow. I don't know what is wrong with it

Command like  `python manage.py runserver` takes 3 minutes to load

Project dependencies

```
amqp==2.2.2
anyjson==0.3.3
appdirs==1.4.3
autopep8==1.3.5
billiard==3.5.0.3
cached-property==1.4.2
celery==4.2.0rc3
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.5.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.0.6
django-annoying==0.10.3
django-celery-beat==1.1.1
django-cors-headers==2.2.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-redis==4.9.0
django-silk==3.0.0
djangorestframework==3.8.2
djangorestframework-xml==1.3.0
gprof2dot==2016.10.13
gunicorn==19.8.1
idna==2.6
isodate==0.6.0
Jinja2==2.10
kombu==4.1.0
lxml==4.2.1
Markdown==2.6.11
MarkupSafe==1.0
psycopg2==2.7.4
psycopg2-binary==2.7.4
pycodestyle==2.4.0
PyConfigure==0.5.9
Pygments==2.2.0
PyStaticConfiguration==0.10.3
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.4
PyYAML==3.12
redis==2.10.6
requests==2.18.4
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
six==1.11.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
structlog==18.1.0
urllib3==1.22
vine==1.1.4
whitenoise==3.3.1
zeep==2.5.0
```

UPDATE

I found that i am using zeep client on my **init**.py

```
wsdl = 'http: . . . '
client = zeep.Client(wsdl)
```

How can i use it so that it doesn't hold server from starting

Comment: What about other commands, e.g. 'python manage.py shell'? In general this sort of thing is almost impossible to debug for remote strangers.

Comment: All management commands takes more than a minute @RemcoGerlich

Comment: i think probably it's because of redis or celery.. but i am not really sure, you can try uninstalling it and try.

Comment: Update @RemcoGerlich

Comment: Don't do things at module level that can take a long time. Put that code in a function and only call it when needed.